# How to add dns address for a host which is receiving IP address from DHCP

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

I have Ubuntu 16.04.6 server which is receiving IP address from the DHCP server. 
I would like to add another DNS server address in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Since it is auto-generated and using DHCP, I am unable to add in `/etc/network/interfaces` as well. One possible way is to edit the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, but since it is not persistence, I have to change the file often.

Another thing would be copying the DHCP IP address details and make a statick connection, but I don't want to do that. 
Any other solution that would work?

Comment: Is this a desktop or server? If a desktop, add the DNS in Network Manager. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091446/where-is-the-proper-place-to-add-a-custom-dns-ip-to-an-ubuntu-16-04-server-that/1091456#1091456) help?

Comment: Please try this. It is a bit old but looks promising: https://askubuntu.com/questions/623704/dynamic-ip-with-static-dns